# How to create a large checklist page with React?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, frontend, next.js

I want to create a page with 100 checklist items. Items will be read from and updated to a firestore document.

My current approach:

```
// define states which hold checkbox value
  const [checkA, setCheckA] = useState(false);
  ...
  ...// 100 such states

// writing to firestore
  firestore()..
  .set({
     checkA: checkA
     ... // 100 key,value pairs
   })

// JAX
  return(
    <checklist
       label= 'checkA'
    />
    <checklist
       label= 'checkB'
    />
    ... // 100 such components
  )
```

Is there a better and less laborious way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't it be easier if you stored a single object in the state for the 100 items?

You could then keep changing the state like this depending upon the logic (if it's an object):

```
setCheckList({...checkList, checkA: false})
```

When you store to firestore, you could directly use the object in your state.

**Edit**

First, define a state variable that will hold all the checklist items

```
const [checkList, setCheckList] = React.useState({checkA: false, checkB: false....100 items})
```

In your checklist component, this is how you would set the new state.

```
<CheckBox label="CheckA" onChange={(value)=>setCheckList({...checkList, checkA: value)} />


<CheckBox label="CheckB" onChange={(value)=>setCheckList({...checkList, checkB: value)} />
```

What you can also probebaly do is to generate the JSX for this dynamically by mapping through checkList instead of adding a hundred checkbox elements which is still cumbersome, something like this:

```
return checkList.map((item, index)=><CheckBox id={index} label={item} onChange={(value)=>{setCheckList({...checkList, [item]: value} />);
```

Finally, storing to firebase should be as easy as:

```
firesStore().set(checkList);
```

Comment: hey, I am new to react. can you please point me to a complete example?

Comment: hey added more details for the approach I would probably take..

Comment: I am facing a bug. This {setCheckList({...checkList, "actual item string": value} } works fine. But {setCheckList({...checkList, item: value} } creates a additional 101th checkbox with "item" as value. I am using Material UI checkbox. any ideas?

Comment: solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/65509513/9499646