# what is the correct syntax to update react hook state of Objects

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of 100 checklists stored in
`const [checkList, setCheckList] = React.useState({"checkA": false, "checkB": false....100 items})`

in the `onClick`, I do

```
 setCheckList({
       ...checkList,
       "checkA": event.target.checked,
  });
```

this works fine, But when I am looping using `.map((item) => {...})`

```
setCheckList({
    ...checkList,
    item: event.target.checked,
});
```

creates 101th checkbox called "item"

What am I missing?

Comment: are you using checkbox inside map function ? and what's json structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using 'item' as a property name and you should put the item in brackets like this:

```
setCheckList({
    ...checkList,
    [item]: event.target.checked,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

a common approach when updating a state of input objects would pass `event.target.name` as key to your update state. you should also at your input declare a `name` attribute with proper matching key:

```
setCheckList({
    ...checkList,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
});
```